# java vtk error: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, vtk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I try to run my vtk application, but got this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\myAppDir\vtk\lib\vtkChartsCoreJava.dll: Can't find dependent libraries 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857) 
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) 
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) 
        at vtk.vtkNativeLibrary.LoadLibrary(vtkNativeLibrary.java:240) 
        at vtk.vtkNativeLibrary.LoadAllNativeLibraries(vtkNativeLibrary.java:175)
```

The application run with:  C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\java.exe" -Djava.library.pathr=myAppDir/vtk/lib ...

I can not add " D:\myAppDir\vtk\lib\" into the PATH, because they are going to 
be packaged into my application.
How can I fix it?
Thanks for all!

Comment: Are all the other VTK libraries also in myAppDir/vtk/lib?

Comment: @PauloCarvalho yes.

Comment: Have you investigated possibly missing dependencies of vtkChartsCoreJava.dll with Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/)?

Comment: Missing API-MS-WIN-***.dll, how to fix it?

Comment: It seems you need to update Windows.